# How to use remote api google app engine api client side?

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, servlets

I'm testing an app on my GAE. I've added:

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>Remote API Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

on `web.xml` (server).
Now, how can I retrieve kind stored in datastore online from local?
 localhost --> servlet client local --> api --> datastore online. Datastore online --> local.
Have you an example of client servlet that retrieves a list of user (or list, objects...) stored in datastore?

Answer (score 0):

add these dependecies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-remote-api</artifactId>
  <version>${appengine.sdk.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

later use something like this :

```
RemoteApiOptions options = new RemoteApiOptions()
    .server("your_app_id.appspot.com", 443)
    .useApplicationDefaultCredential();

RemoteApiInstaller installer = new RemoteApiInstaller();
installer.install(options);
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query q=new Query("User"); 
Iterator<Entity> c=ds.prepare(q).asQueryResultIterator();
while (c.hasNext())
 {System.out.println(c.next());}
 installer.uninstall();
```

and refer to the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/remoteapi)

Comment: got it, but i'm getting some errors like: (on server) "This request did not contain a necessary header"; (on client) "302 error" when i call my servlet to retrieve information like you wrote or when i try to get datastore kind with python script (appcfg.py).

Comment: did you access it via browser? and did you add the servlet in web.xml?

Comment: sure. I added everything in web.xml. From client i use "localhost:8888/test_remote_api", where 'test_remote_api' is the servlet with code to retrieve informations.